# Obsidian: After pressing Tab-Key and writing Text, Backlinks don't work anymore

Tags: obsidian

Obsidian: After pressing Tab-Key and writing Text, Backlinks don't work anymore.
How can I make the backlink work again?

```
    Text [[Backlink]]
```